# Best Index for query with window functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having some performance issues with a query in SQL Server 2012.

The query is used to insert data in a table using window functions to aggregate sales data in different ways (Previous month, previous year month, Cycle to date, YTD, MAT).

After doing a pretty extensive research in windows functions I think that an appropriate index in the table from which the data is read would help a lot, but I am struggling to find the correct one (too many columns involved)...

The source table from which the table reads the data has around 50 million rows and is truncated and reloaded in a daily basis by an SSIS package that can be modified to drop and create the indexes in each execution.

Could somebody suggest what index might work (if any) or any other performance improvement method?

The select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    PERIOD,
    CUENTA_ID,
    PROD_ID,
    TIPO_VENTA,
    VENTA_EUROS,
    CICLO,
    DELEGADO_B2B,

    SUM(VENTA_EUROS)                OVER (PARTITION BY CUENTA_ID, PROD_ID, TIPO_VENTA,DELEGADO_B2B              ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 12 PRECEDING) AS VENTA_EUROS_PREV,
    SUM(VENTA_EUROS)                OVER (PARTITION BY CUENTA_ID, PROD_ID, TIPO_VENTA,DELEGADO_B2B,YEAR         ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS VENTA_EUROS_YTD,
    SUM(VENTA_EUROS)                OVER (PARTITION BY CUENTA_ID, PROD_ID, TIPO_VENTA,DELEGADO_B2B,YEAR, CICLO  ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS VENTA_EUROS_CTD,
    SUM(VENTA_EUROS)                OVER (PARTITION BY CUENTA_ID, PROD_ID, TIPO_VENTA,DELEGADO_B2B              ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS VENTA_EUROS_MONTH_PREV,
    SUM(VENTA_EUROS)                OVER (PARTITION BY CUENTA_ID, PROD_ID, TIPO_VENTA,DELEGADO_B2B              ORDER BY PERIOD ROWS 11 PRECEDING) AS VENTA_EUROS_MAT

FROM _REPORTING.[dbo].[RPT_VENTA_MENSUAL_STEP_1]
WHERE YEAR>=YEAR(DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()))-1
```

I checked the execution plan and the parts that are taking the biggest percentages are the three sortings for the three different "OVER(PARTITION BY)

Here is the plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1fsgwjBE

Thanks & Regards

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the [execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017) of your query into your question. And also your table structure.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I edited the post with what I got from the execution plan, thanks for the help!

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: Thanks @HABO, I edited the post with the link to the query plan

Comment: I don't know about `ORDER BY` within a windowing function, but the biggest speed boost for a normal `ORDER BY` is to create the clustered index on that column

Answer (score 0):

The first thing the index needs to resolve is the `WHERE` clause.  Unfortunately, it has an inequality, which pretty much makes it impossible for the optimizer to help with the windowing clauses.

If you had:

```
WHERE YEAR = YEAR(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) - 1
```

Then the optimizer could take advantage of an index on `(YEAR, CUENTA_ID, PROD_ID, TIPO_VENTA, DELEGADO_B2B, PERIOD)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, would it help if I changed the WHERE clause to: ```WHERE YEAR = YEAR(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) - 1 OR WHERE YEAR = YEAR(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) ``` (since I need current and previous year only)?

Comment: @LuisGarcia-Moreno . . . `OR` is an index killer.  Try running with just one year.  If that works, you can construct the query using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thanks! I can remove the where entirely, since right now the source table already contains current and previous year